# `docker-machine env $VMNAME` hangs even when I'm _not_ using a VPN client like Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: docker, docker-machine

So, I ran across this today on my local Mac OS X (Yosemite) machine.

I was doing a bunch of stuff related to Docker images and when I tried to run `docker` commands I was getting errors. I've had problems before where a `docker-machine restart default` fixed my problem, but that didn't seem to help. After booting, I could `docker ssh default` and get into the box, but `docker-machine env default` would just hang.

Googling turned up this Github issue: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1500. It didn't address my issue as I don't run VPN software.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm answering my own question.)

If you're having this issue and not using a VPN, look to see if your VirtualBox's VM is full.

The problem is/was that I'd pulled so many images down, that the VirtualBox VM's hard disk was completely full.

I'm sure there are more elegant approaches, but I just deleted the vm and created a new one.

I did: `docker-machine rm default && docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

Once I did that, I was successfully able to use docker as normal. Of course I had to re-pull and/or re-build all my images, but that was pretty fast and not a big deal.